# django-supervisor connection refused

Tags: python, django, supervisord, django-supervisor

I am using supervisor to run celery with a django 1.8.8. setup. also using `django-supervisor==0.3.4
supervisor==3.2.0`

but when i restart all proecsses, i get

```
unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock refused connection
```

not able to restart any processes,

```
python manage.py supervisor --config-file=setting/staging_supervisor.conf --settings=setting.staging_settings restart all
```

supervisor config file

```
[supervisord]
    logfile_maxbytes=10MB                                                       ; maximum size of logfile before rotation
    logfile_backups=3                                                           ; number of backed up logfiles
    loglevel=warn                                                               ; info, debug, warn, trace
    nodaemon=false                                                              ; run supervisord as a daemon
    minfds=1024                                                                 ; number of startup file descriptors
    minprocs=200                                                                ; number of process descriptors
    childlogdir=/logs/                    ; where child log files will live

    [program:celeryd_staging]
    environment=PATH="{{ PROJECT_DIR }}/../../bin"
    command={{ PYTHON }} {{ PROJECT_DIR }}/manage.py celeryd -l info -c 1 --logfile=/logs/staging-celeryd.log --settings=setting.staging_celery_settings
    redirect_stderr=false

    [program:celerybeat_staging]
    environment=PATH="{{ PROJECT_DIR }}/../../bin"
    command=/{{ PYTHON }} {{ PROJECT_DIR }}/manage.py celerybeat --loglevel=INFO --logfile=/logs/staging-celerybeat.log --settings=setting.staging_celery_settings
    redirect_stderr=false

    [group:tasks]
    environment=PATH="{{ PROJECT_DIR}}/../../bin"
    programs=celeryd_staging,celerybeat_staging

    [program:autoreload]
    exclude=true

    [program:runserver]
    exclude=true
```

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution. The supervisor process was not reloaded as supervisord was in my virtual enve as i ma using django-supervisor package.

once i reloaded the supervisor process, the refused connection error went away.

Answer (score 0):

make sure there isn't already another `/tmp/supervisor.sock` owned by some user other than you (like root or something).

if not a permissions problem, add this to your supervisord configuration:

```
[unix_http_server]
file = /tmp/supervisor.sock ;
chmod=0700 ;

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory =
supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface
```

this might be helpful to you as well: https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/480#issuecomment-145193475

Comment: @matiaselegart: there is just one file, owned by the same user

Comment: is this running on a Docker instance, by any chance?

Comment: so just for fun, can you run it with sudo in front? just to rule out perms problems?

Comment: it is not possible as everything runs on a virtual env. ut just for satisfaction i did run with sudo, no luck

Comment: How did you install your supervisor? Are you on ubuntu 16?

Comment: if you get a chance, try setting the perms on the socket file to `0660`, with owner and group of the file the same to the owner of the python process you're running to start supervisor.

Comment: @WilliamR.Marchand, i nstalled django-supervisor and supervisor package via pip, i have not done any installation of supervisor like sudo apt-get install supervisor.

Comment: @matiaselgart, i have tried is with multiple permissions including 777, 760, 660. but no result.

Comment: did you try just deleting the file and starting the process again? (just to rule out other issues) -- basically, did this ever work for you?

Comment: You will get that error if you try to do supervisorctl as root, is you are root it means supervisor is not started yet.

Comment: @matiaselgart: if i delete the .sock file, then i get unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock no such file

Comment: @WilliamR.Marchand: I am not a root user but my user does not require root password to run sudo commands.

Comment: @matiaselgart: Thanks, i figured it out and have posted the solution, please check it. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @WilliamR.Marchand: Thanks for the help :)